# Overflow-x iPod touch

Tags: css, overflow, mobile-safari

I'm creating a mobile version of a site. I have 3 divs, each 33.33% wide of a body with a width of 300%, (so they're all the full width of the screen), floated left so they're all side-by-side, and you can slide between the divs by clicking links.

I've added `overflow-x: hidden;` to the body tag to remove the horizontal scrollbar. This works fine on a desktop, but on my iPod touch, I can still drag and scroll horizontally using my finger, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the HTML `head` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

This will set the width of your page to the width of the device viewing it. On an iOS device it will also disable the pinch-to-zoom gesture.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a width of `300%` on a wrapper element within the `body`. If you have both a `width:300%` and `overflow-x:hidden` on the body, you'd only be hiding content within the `body` if the content you wish to hide is greater than 300% wide.

See [my example](http://codepen.io/galenwilk/pen/pKqat) using a wrapper within `body`.